# Remove last 4 characters using VB script from folder name

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VB script and trying to create a script in which i am looping in a folder and printing all the  subfolder names in a output text file.

All the subfolders have same 4 characters at the -tst , i want to remove this last 4 character and print rest of the name.

For example - original name - Test_name-tst
expected output name - Test_name .

```
    'Creates new log file and write in it
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    outFile="D:\Test\test_output.LOG"
    Set objFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

    objFile.Write  "START_" & vbCrLf
strFolder ="C:\apps\Test\"
    'Get a reference to the folder you want to search
    Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Subfolders
    'Loop through the folder and get the file names
    For Each Fil In FLD
    If InStr(Fil.Name , "-prj") Then
        objFile.Write Fil.Name & vbCrLf
End If
    Next
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the Left() and Len() functions

Comment: This is barely a question, as @ArnovanBoven has already said `Left(Fil.Name, Len(Fil.Name) - 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Left and len worked for me.

var1 = Left(Fil.Name, Len(Fil.Name) - 4)

Answer (score -2):

Reverse the name, cut the first four characters with `Mid()` and reverse the string again:

```
StrReverse(Mid(StrReverse(Fil.Name), 5))
```

Comment: Not sure reversing a string twice to do what `Left()` and `Len()` can do without reversing the string is an efficient approach.